# Move method code to Neo4j Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, spring-data-neo4j

I have a Spring Neo4j repository method `getAvgVotesWeightForCriterion`

```
@Query("MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(v:Vote)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Criterion) WHERE id(d) = {0} AND id(c) = {1} RETURN avg(v.weight)")
double getAvgVotesWeightForCriterion(Decision decision, Criterion criterion);
```

and also I have another method `calculateWeight` completely written in Java. This method internally in loop uses `getAvgVotesWeightForCriterion`

```
public double calculateWeight(Decision decision, List<Criterion> criteria) {
    double weight = 0;

    for (Criterion criterion : criteria) {
        weight += getAvgVotesWeightForCriterion(decision, criterion);
    }

    return weight;
}
```

Is it possible to move logic inside `calculateWeight` method completely to Cypher query ? In order to get something like this:

```
@Query ....
double calculateWeight(Decision decision, List<Criterion> criteria)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want to do.

You group the avg - aggregation per criterion and then just sum the weights.

```
MATCH (d:Decision)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(v:Vote)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Criterion) 
WHERE id(d) = {0} AND id(c) IN {1} 
WITH c, avg(v.weight) as weight
RETURN sum(weight)
```